# How to animate font size in Slick2D, without creating a new font instance each render?

Tags: java, performance, animation, lwjgl, slick2d

I'm working in Slick2D, a wrapper for the LWJGL. I'm trying to animate/scale the font size of a string, without having the performance cost of creating a new Font and TrueTypeFont each render. Here's what I currently have:

```
public void render(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, Graphics g) throws SlickException {
    Font pulsingFont = new Font("Verdana", Font.PLAIN, (int) Math.abs(Math.sin(frameCount) * 20) + 10);
    TrueTypeFont pulsing = new TrueTypeFont(pulsingFont, true);
    pulsing.drawString(200, 200, "Pulsing Text", Color.black);
}

public void update(GameContainer gc, StateBasedGame sbg, int DELTA) throws SlickException {
    frameCount += 0.1;
}
```

The only way I know to change to font size is in Font, which means I also need to make a new instance of a TrueTypeFont *every single frame*. Just these lines alone cause massive lag.

So is there a way to **animate a font size without create a new instance each frame?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can scale the Graphics component.
This will scale everything though, so make sure to rescale it after you are down with rendering you text.

Note that you will have to adapt your x/y position due to the increment/decrement of your graphics scale.

From the Slick2d doc:
http://slick.ninjacave.com/javadoc/org/newdawn/slick/Graphics.html :

```
    scale(float sx, float sy) 
    Apply a scaling factor to everything drawn on the graphics context
```

That means you could scale up or down the graphics component.
Render your text.
Rescale your graphics component back to normal.
Do the rest of your rendering.